# Select all but sort by count in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sorting, count

I have a table `myTable` with a lot of columns, keep in mind this table is too big, and one of that columns is a geometry point, we'll call it `mySortColumn`. I need to sort my select by count `mySortColumn` when there are the same.

One example could be this

```
myTable

id, mySortColumn
----------------
1, ASD12321F
2, ASD12321G
3, ASD12321F
4, ASD12321G
5, ASD12321H
6, ASD12321F
```

I have a query which can do what I want, the problem is the time. Actually it take like 30 seconds, and it seems like this:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  mySortColumn
FROM
  myTable
JOIN (
  SELECT
    mySortColumn,
    ST_Y(mySortColumn) AS lat,
    ST_X(mySortColumn) AS lng,
    COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY mySortColumn
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS myPosition ON (
  ST_X(myTable.mySortColumn) = myPosition.lng
  AND ST_Y(myTable.mySortColumn) = myPosition.lat
)
WHERE
  <some filters>
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

The result must be this:

```
id, mySortColumn
----------------
1, ASD12321F
3, ASD12321F
6, ASD12321F
2, ASD12321G
4, ASD12321G
5, ASD12321H
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
select * from myTable order by count(1) over (partition by mySortColumn) desc;
```

For more info about `aggregate over ()` construction have a look at:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html